# How can I set view pager's on Item Click Listener? Set On Click Listener is not working

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, onclicklistener, viewpagerindicator

How can I set view pager's on **Item Click Listener**. I want to detect **click** on **view pager's current item**. Set `On Click Listener` is not working.

I am having Direct View Pager in my application and i am setting its adapter with a class that extends fragment and assigning that fragment to view pager's adapter. Now I want to detect `item click` or I can say individual fragment click so how can I do that?

please anyone help me I am badly stuck into this problem and not finding any related solution. I have done so much search but not able to find solution for this.

Comment: Did you try: `vPager.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener()){

    @Override
    public boolean onClick(View v) {
        // Do something
        return false;
    }
});` - or what have you tried ?

Comment: @g00dy i have tried on Click Listener which is not working for individual fragment item click.and view pager is not allowing to set on touch listener

Comment: do you have an error output or how come it's not allowing that?

Comment: There's also a logged bug for this OcClick listener in a specific situation, see if that's you case: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37256&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Comment: @g00dy when i am clicking on any item nothing happens.code inside the on click listener is not getting executed. if you say i can upload the entire code.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the onClickListener on the individual  pages of the view Pager within the **instantiateItem** method  I have tried for simple images within a  view pager

```
 @Override
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, final int pos) { //have to make final so we can see it inside of onClick()

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    View page = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_PAGE, null);

    page.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            //this will log the page number that was click
            Log.i("TAG", "This page was clicked: " + pos);
        }
    });


    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(page, 0);
    return page;
}
```

you can refer to the original post here 
[ViewPager OnItemClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350987/viewpager-onitemclicklistener)

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by implement `OnPageChangeListener`

```
public class LeftPanelPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements OnPageChangeListener{
        .....
        .....
        ....

private int currentSelectedFragmentPosition = 0; 
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
        currentSelectedFragmentPosition = arg0;

    }

    public int getCurrentSelectedFragmentPosition() {
        return currentSelectedFragmentPosition;
    }



}
```