# How can i add setOnClickLister method for this Library in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-view, android-library

I want to use this library in my application:  https://github.com/Devlight/InfiniteCycleViewPager

I imported and added this library in my application and I set it.
But I don't know how can I use the `setOnClickListener()` method for these  viewPager items?

For instance, when I click on item1, go to this item: `fragment`

How can I do that?

Comment: ask the developer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do some changes in this library go through this [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16351030/6333971) and sample of that library Where u can change for on click [link2](https://github.com/Devlight/InfiniteCycleViewPager/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/gigamole/sample/adapters/HorizontalPagerAdapter.java)

Comment: Thanks my friend <3

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Just set a page change listener for your InfiniteCycleViewPager and it will call the method onPageSelected(int position) when click on view.

```
YourInfiniteCycleViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
```

To retrieve the right position for the InfiniteCycleViewPager you should call getRealItem() when onPageSelected called.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an adapter for your InfiniteCycleViewPager, for example YourAdapter.java which extends PagerAdapter. Then set this adapter to 
yourInfiniteCycleViewPager.setAdapter(mYourAdapter);

In override method: instantiateItem(ViewGroup, int), you can simply add your onClick listener and add logic to it:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, fianl int position) {

    ....

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.xxx_your_layout, null);

    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             // TODO
             // do your code, and you can use variable 'position' here.
        }
    });
}
```