# Layout setOnClickListener Not Working

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

Past Few days,Facing this problem .I know about **[NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)** .
Fragment launch to crashing .

**Java**

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_home,container,false);


        final Dialog alertDialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        alertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        alertDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_viewpager);
        alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        alertDialog.show();
        viewPager = (ViewPager)alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        // layouts of all welcome sliders
        // add few more layouts if you want
              layouts = new int[]{
                R.layout.welcome_slide1,
                R.layout.welcome_slide2,
                R.layout.welcome_slide3,

        }

        myViewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);

        RelativeLayout rl_header_thirdObj=(RelativeLayout)alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.rl_header_third);
    //Here//    rl_header_thirdObj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }

    return view;
}
```

**Crash**

> at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)   Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   com.fragment.FragmentHome.onCreateView

Indicate  Line  **rl_header_thirdObj.setOnClickListener** .

**FYI**

**RelativeLayout rl_header_thirdObj** presents in **welcome_slide3.xml** .

May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective? Does any guys meet this issue?Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: post your `fragment_tab_home` layout

Comment: `fragment_tab_home ` is simple .Parent is `Relative Layout` and have `Button`

Comment: post your layout xml files.

Answer (score 1):

Here `Relativelayout` is not a part of your `alertDialog` view.

so instead of:

```
 RelativeLayout rl_header_thirdObj=(RelativeLayout)alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.rl_header_third);
```

use:

```
 RelativeLayout rl_header_thirdObj=(RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.rl_header_third);
```

Comment: where are you using `layouts[]` ?

Comment: i would suggest you to add `rl_header_thirdObj` in alertdialog layout `dialog_viewpager`..apply the above code

Comment: `dialog_viewpager` xml is parent of viewpager which hold 3 layouts .If onclick events not sets then it works

Comment: For Viewpager If you want click events on each page then you'll have to build your listener into the page content within your Adapter.: see this for [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350987/viewpager-onitemclicklistener)