# Clickable viewpager onItem click is not working inside fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have my custom viewpager to achieve onItemClick so I took a reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350987/viewpager-onitemclicklistener). When I put that Viewpager inside Activity it is working fine but when I put inside a fragment then it stops fire onItemClick event.

I am using data binding for activity and fragment code. I guess proper touch event is not passing to the custom viewpager.

How can I achieve onItemClick on custom viewpager?

Please correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

Thanks in advance.

**Custom Viewpager**

```
public class ClickableViewPager extends ViewPager {
        private OnViewPagerItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;
        private GestureDetector tapGestureDetector;

    public ClickableViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setup();
    }

    public ClickableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setup();
    }

    private void setup() {
        tapGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), new TapGestureListener());

        this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                DebugHelper.log("ClickableViewPager : OnTouchListener");
                tapGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                return false;
            }
        });


    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnViewPagerItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        mOnItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }

    public interface OnViewPagerItemClickListener {
        void onViewPagerItemClick(int position);
    }

    private class TapGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            DebugHelper.log("ClickableViewPager : TapGestureListener : onSingleTapConfirmed");
            if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                mOnItemClickListener.onViewPagerItemClick(getCurrentItem());
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

**View Pager Adapter**

```
public class OnGoingServiceAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Activity activity;
    private List<HistoryModel> onGoingServiceList;
    private Interfaces.OnMoreServiceClick onMoreServiceClick;

    public OnGoingServiceAdapter(Activity context, List<HistoryModel> onGoingServiceList, Interfaces.OnMoreServiceClick onMoreServiceClick) {
        activity = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.onGoingServiceList = onGoingServiceList;
        this.onMoreServiceClick = onMoreServiceClick;
    }


    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
        OngoingServiceItemBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.ongoing_service_item, collection, false);
        binding.setOnGoingService(this.onGoingServiceList.get(position));
        binding.ivCall.setTag(position);
        binding.ivCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = (int) v.getTag();
                StaticUtils.onPhoneClick(activity, getItem(position).getPhone());
            }
        });
        binding.tvMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (onMoreServiceClick != null) {
                    onMoreServiceClick.onMoreCurrentServiceItemClick();
                }
            }
        });
        collection.addView(binding.getRoot());
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        View view = (View) object;
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView(view);
        view = null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.onGoingServiceList == null ? 0 : this.onGoingServiceList.size();   //onGoingServiceList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    public HistoryModel getItem(int position) {
        return this.onGoingServiceList.get(position);
    }

    public void updateData(List<HistoryModel> servicesList) {
        this.onGoingServiceList = servicesList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: You take custom ViewPager only to resolve click event?

Comment: I need onItem Click that's why I took custom view pager and When I set click event on my root view it does not swipe my view properly.

Comment: And you want all activitis or fragments inside viewpager?

Comment: My viewpager display simple XML file. I put my Viewpager inside one standalone fragment