# How can i open new activity by clicking on banner which i had implemented using viewpager?

Tags: android, arraylist

i have implemented an auto rotating banner with `viewpager` and handling images with `arraylist` but i want to open new activity on clicking to the banner which i had used i am not getting how to handle it listeners

Code :

```
package com.example.demoapp;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static ViewPager mPager;
private static int currentPage = 0;
private static int NUM_PAGES = 0;
private ArrayList<ImageModel> imageModelArrayList;
private int[] myImageList = new int[]{R.drawable.ban, R.drawable.bann,
        R.drawable.banne,R.drawable.banner
        ,R.drawable.banne,R.drawable.cover};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    imageModelArrayList = populateList();

    init();

}

public ArrayList<ImageModel> populateList(){

    ArrayList<ImageModel> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        ImageModel imageModel = new ImageModel();
        imageModel.setImage_drawable(myImageList[i]);
        list.add(imageModel);
    }

    return list;
}

private void init() {

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(new SlidingImage_Adapter(MainActivity.this,imageModelArrayList));

    CirclePageIndicator indicator = (CirclePageIndicator)
            findViewById(R.id.indicator);

    indicator.setViewPager(mPager);

    final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

 //Set circle indicator radius
    indicator.setRadius(5 * density);

    NUM_PAGES =imageModelArrayList.size();

    // Auto start of viewpager
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES) {
                currentPage = 0;
            }
            mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
        }
    };
    Timer swipeTimer = new Timer();
    swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(Update);
        }
    }, 3000, 3000);

    // Pager listener over indicator
    indicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            currentPage = position;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int pos, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int pos) {

        }
    });

}

}
```

Needed help in `onclick` should open new activity.i had tried various thing but it doesn't worked for me.if anyone have alternative to implement auto rotating banner with on click should open new activity

Comment: add `SlidingImage_Adapter.java` to the question please for clarity

Comment: It would be good if you send code for SlidingImage_Adapter.java. You need to put onClick event in the item layout inside you adapter class.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom view pager class which can be clickable

```html
public class ClickableViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;

    public ClickableViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setup();
    }

    public ClickableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setup();
    }

    private void setup() {
        final GestureDetector tapGestureDetector = new    GestureDetector(getContext(), new TapGestureListener());

        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                tapGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        mOnItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    private class TapGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            if(mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(getCurrentItem());
            }
            return true;
       }
    }
}
```

and implement an anonymous type listener

```html
ClickableViewPager viewPager = (ClickableViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
viewPager.setOnItemClickListener(new ClickableViewPager.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {
                // your code
            }
        });
```

Refered from question [ViewPager OnItemClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350987/viewpager-onitemclicklistener)